# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient: Receiving cookies and save them

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, windows-runtime, httpclient

I need some help with the new `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` Class. I am writing my first WP8.1 App right now and it drives me crazy. I am logging into a website like this:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("login_username", _username);
values.Add("login_password", _password);
values.Add("login_lifetime", "36000");

var parameters = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await Forum.Http.PostAsync(new Uri("http://foo.bar.xyz"), parameters);

var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
byte[] byteArray = buffer.ToArray();
string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

if (content.Contains("Wrong password/user name"))
{
        return false;
}

return true;
```

And this works pretty fine. My HttpClient is a static field, like this:

```
public static HttpBaseProtocolFilter Filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
public static HttpClient Http = new HttpClient(Filter);
```

The login works just fine, but it doesn't save the cookies the website sends after logging in. How can I save them and can I send them to the website on every GetAsync()?

Answer (score -1):

You can use HttpClientHandler instead of HttpBaseProtocolFilter.  If you must use HttpBaseProtocolFilter, then there is a read-only CookieManager property of type HttpCookieManager that could help you.

Here's an example using HttpClientHandler:

```
public static CookieContainer Cookies = new CookieContainer();
public static HttpClientHandler HttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = Cookies };
public static HttpClient Http = new HttpClient(HttpClientHandler);
```

After your PostAsync() call returns, you can extract the cookies

```
var uri = new Uri("http://foo.bar.xyz");
var response = await Forum.Http.PostAsync(uri, parameters);
IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = Cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies) {
    Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
}
```

If you'd like to re-use a cookie from the initial request, you can create your own CookieContainer and copy the cookie from the response cookies.  Or - you could also add a hard-coded cookie like this:

```
Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Name", "Value") { Domain="http://foo.bar.xyz" });
```

Comment: As far as I know Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient does not use HttpClientHandler. Am I wrong?

Comment: I implemented your solution (had to use System.Net.Http.HttpClient instead). Everything still works fine. But it won't receive or save any cookies. My CookieContainer is still empty. It really drives me crazy.